# Error with HTTP Post in python requests library

Tags: python, dictionary, flask

I am not able to send a http post request via python(Flask).

Here is my python code.

```
import json
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import requests
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/",methods=['GET','POST'])
def home():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #user inputs
        value1 = request.form.get('first')
        value2 = request.form.get('second')
        value3 = request.form.get('third')


        #api call 
        url = 'http://myapiurl.com/ws/spm/spm-general'
        payload = {"perfid" : {0}, "section" : {"hostname" : {1}, "iteration" : {2}, "sectionname" : "sysstat_M"}.format(value1,value2,value3)}



        r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))

        #print(r.status_code, r.headers['content-type'])
        #print(r.text)

        returnData["result"] = json.loads(r.text)
        return jsonify(returnData)

    return render_template('index.html')





if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I am using FLASK.
The error I am getting is :

```
 payload = {"perfid" : {0}, "section" : {"hostname" : {1}, "iteration" : {2},
 "sectionname" : "sysstat_M"}.format(value1,value2,value3)}
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'format'
```

When I try it in simple python(without Flask) it works , but I am not able to do it with Flask

Here is the code which works:

```
import json
import requests


url = 'http://myapiurl.com/ws/spm/spm-general'
payload = {"perfid" : 124, "section" : {"hostname" : "10.161.146.94/10.161.146.90", "iteration" : "1", "sectionname" : "sysstat_M"}}

r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload))


print(r.status_code, r.headers['content-type'])
print(r.text)
```

Comment: The error says `dict` has no `format` method. So, remove it and hard-code all values you tried to pass with `format`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you're confused `dict` with `str` (which has a [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) method).

Just put the variables to the dictionary literal:

```
payload = {
    "perfid" : value1,
    "section" : {
        "hostname" : value2,
        "iteration" : value3,
        "sectionname" : "sysstat_M"
    }
}
```

Comment: This did it :)
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

```
payload = {"perfid" : value1, "section" : {"hostname" : value2, "iteration" : value3, "sectionname" : "sysstat_M"}
```

`format` is a function for `string`, please look this: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format

Comment: You linked wrong function: `format` is a function, you should link `str.format` method.